# What is the way to declare mdbreact's type while installing?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

I am new to typescript react and I am trying to use mdbreact to create my navbar, those are my importations:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  MDBNavbar,
  MDBNavbarBrand,
  MDBNavbarNav,
  MDBNavItem,
  MDBNavLink,
  MDBNavbarToggler,
  MDBCollapse,
  MDBDropdown,
  MDBDropdownToggle,
  MDBDropdownMenu,
  MDBDropdownItem,
  MDBIcon,
} from "mdbreact";
```

But I am getting this error:

```
TypeScript error in C:/projects/breaking-news/news-project/src/App.tsx(15,8):
Cannot find module 'mdbreact' or its corresponding type declarations.  TS2307

    13 |   MDBDropdownItem,
    14 |   MDBIcon,
  > 15 | } from "mdbreact";
       |        ^
    16 | import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
    17 |
    18 | class NavbarPage extends Component {
```

and I believe it is something about declaring mdbreact's type while installing but I don't know how and I googled it but nothing helped.

Comment: This package seems to have built-in declarations so you shouldn't need to do anything other than make sure that the package is installed.

Comment: I already installed the package but it didn't work, the thing is I think it needs to be installed somehow like npm i --save-dev @types/(and then something here) but the thing is I didn't discover what I should do exactly.

Comment: You would use `@types/mdbreact` if the types were not included in the package and were managed by [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).  But that is not the case here.  npm [says](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdbreact) that the TypeScript types are included with the main `mbdreact` package.  So you do not need to install anything from `@types/`.  You just need `npm i mdbreact`.

Comment: But trust me I did and I am getting the same error.

Comment: When you have an error that shouldn't be an error it's a "turn everything off and on again" situation.  Unfortunately I can't help you beyond that because I don't know why you would be getting this error.

Comment: I'll try thank you.